# Creating a single boxplot from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have three dataframes containing only one column, 'Time', and differing numbers of rows of pandas `datetime` values. Ex:

```
      Time
0  3 days    
1  16 days   
2  6 days     
3  4 days     
4  4 days     
5  4 days
```

I would like to create a single box plot (candlestick) that has three bars representing the distribution of the times in all dataframes side by side.
How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could accomplish this by adding a column to each dataframe which holds an information to group the single values. Here is a small example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I have generated only some random int values.

```
time1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,30,10), columns=['Time'] )
time2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,30,10), columns=['Time'] )
time3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,30,10), columns=['Time'] )
```

Instead of `int` values you can also use the pands `Timedelta`. But you need to get the days value.

```
time1 = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timedelta(days=random.randint(0,30)).days for x in range(10)], columns=['Time'] )
time2 = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timedelta(days=random.randint(0,30)).days for x in range(10)], columns=['Time'] )
time3 = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timedelta(days=random.randint(0,30)).days for x in range(10)], columns=['Time'] )
```

Then I added the column "Data" to each dataframe with a unique identifier.

```
time1["Data"] = "A"
time2["Data"] = "B"
time3["Data"] = "C"
```

Now I concatenate all dataframe.

```
times = [time1, time2, time3]
allTimes = pd.concat(times)
```

With the method [boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) you can group now the data by the column "Data"

```
plt.figure()
allTimes.boxplot(by="Data")
```

This results in following image:

[image]

Comment: Your time columns in the example contain integers, mine contain date time objects, and plotting in this way didn't work with date times.

Comment: I'v edited my example so that you can see how it works with datetime. You need to call the `days` value of your objects.